# Error submitting a modified field of a form

Tags: python, django

I am having a problem with my form, and it is that when trying to persist my data in the database this is not done correctly, because in my form the developer field is not being validated in the correct way because it does not show an error to the client, but the browser console shows me the following error, an invalid form control with name = 'developer' cannot be focused.
This is my form:

```
class ProjectForm(ModelForm):
    developer = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.filter(groups__name='desarrolladores'),
        label='Desarrolladores',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = (
            'developer', 'name', 'status'
        )
        labels = {
            'name': 'Nombre de Proyecto',
            'status': 'Estado',
        }

    def clean_developer(self):
        developer = self.cleaned_data.get('developer')
        if developer is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError('El campo es obligatorio')
        return developer
```

This is my view:

```
class ProjectCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'users:login'
    template_name = 'projects/add_project.html'
    form_class = ProjectForm
    permission_required = 'projects.add_project'
    success_message = 'Proyecto creado exitosamente'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('projects:project')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['formset'] = ProjectFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            data['formset'] = ProjectFormSet()

        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        with transaction.atomic():
            self.object = form.save()

            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.instance = self.object
                formset.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is my template:

```
<form id="form-container" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <h2>Tareas</h2>
    <table>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
            {% if forloop.first %}
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                            <th>{{ field.label|capfirst }}</th>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            {% endif %}
            <tr id="projects_data">
                {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                    <td>
                        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                        {% if forloop.first %}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}
                        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                        {{ field }}
                    </td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
    <button type="submit" class="button success"><span class="mif-add icon"></span> {{ message }}</button>
    <a href="{% url 'projects:project' %}" class="button alert"><span class="mif-cancel icon"></span> Cancelar</a>
</form>
```

This is error
[image]

Comment: Please show the view that uses the form and verify the browser's developer tools shows a value being sent in the POST for the `developer` field.

Comment: what i have noticed is that if i don't modify my developer field it doesn't generate any error but i need to modify it to show only specific content

Comment: Please include the full errors.

Comment: I already added the error